# jmeter not capturing/recording windows authentication credential window

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

jmeter https test script recorder not capturing/recording windows authentication credential window (may be NTLM) , it is bypassing the window always.. I need to record/capture the username and password. Please let me know how to resolve the issue?

[Windows security authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O5wc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Jmeter documentation
"When looking for a match against a URL, JMeter checks each entry in turn, and stops when it finds the first match. Thus the most specific URLs should appear first in the list, followed by less specific ones. Duplicate URLs will be ignored. If you want to use different usernames/passwords for different threads, you can use variables. These can be set up using a CSV Data Set Config Element."

The above explanation clearly explains that credentials can be parametrized.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter will not be able to capture this window as it doesn't really generate a [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request). When you enter your credentials the browser creates [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header and depending on the header value provider the server either lets you in or not.

JMeter provides [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to deal with external authentication types which may cause these modal pop-ups most probably in your case it is [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or [Kerberos](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/).

So add the HTTP Authorization Manager to your Test Plan and provide your credentials, domain, realm, etc. there - if everything goes well the server will let you in.

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more information on how to deal with external authentication systems in JMeter tests.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for the response, Can we parameterize the credentials from HTTP Authorization manager using CSV data set config? i tried to do the parameterize but always one default windows user logged in and displaying in the response.